# NumberFormatException: For input string: "" while parsing

Tags: java, numberformatexception

I wished to turn a string of single digit integers into an `Integer` ArrayList, and I'm getting a very odd exception. Here's the sample code:

```
    Scanner test = new Scanner(System.in);
    String[] temp = null;
    String line = null;
    ArrayList<Integer> artemp = new ArrayList<>();

    while(test.hasNext()) {
        line = test.next();
        temp = line.split("");
        for(int i = 0; i < temp.length; i++)
        artemp.add(Integer.parseInt(temp[i]));
        for(int i : artemp) System.out.println(i);

    }
```

It is basically supposed to read the string of ints from stdin, put them in an arraylist as primitives, and then print them out. Of course, this is just a small test case to which I narrowed down my larger error.

The exception this raises is the following:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:504)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:527)
```

As far as I can see, the following should take place:

1. `line` takes in stdin
2. `temp` gets filled with each of the individual single-digit values (split("") splits after every character)
3. Each digit (stored as a `String`) is parsed as an `int` and added to `artemp`
4. Print out each digit.

What exactly is going wrong here? If I print out `temp` with the following code:

```
for(String s : temp) System.out.println(s);
```

Then the digits get printed successfully (as Strings), and I there are no extra characters. How exactly could `parseInt(temp[i])` be getting applied to the string `""`?

Comment: Do you want to convert string say - `1234`, into individual digits?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all I'm suspecting your split,

```
  temp = line.split("");
```

If you want to split with space ,it should be

```
  temp = line.split(" ");
```

And if you want with `""` only,then here is the cause.

There is nothing to do with conversion.

There are some empty strings in you `array`.

So exception while converting empty string in to integer.

here

```
 artemp.add(Integer.parseInt(temp[i]));
```

What you can do is,check the data before parsing.

```
if(temp[i]!=null && !temp[i].isEmpty()){
          artemp.add(Integer.parseInt(temp[i]));
}
```

Comment: Sometimes it's the simplest of things. Thank you for your swift reply!

For the sake of completeness, would my parsing strategy be any more efficient than using `line.substring(...)`? Or is the gain negligible?

Since your answer was first, I'll be accepting it in 5m.

Comment: Yes. I don't think it would matter too much for my current code, but I cannot find good comparisons between `split` and `substring`.

Comment: Glad ,It helped.Are you asking about using substring,instead of split ??If so,I'l say that go with split method.substring is not needed in this case an performance wise there might be a minor difference/micro optimization.So go for clean and readable code.Make the code as much as less you can with help of built in methods.That substring need few more checks again..like length etc.

Answer (score 0):

From The Docs [parseInt](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt%28java.lang.String%29)

```
Throws:
    NumberFormatException - if the string does not contain a parsable integer.
```

So your Code `artemp.add(Integer.parseInt(temp[i]));` is some where encoutering a unparsable String.

Answer (score 0):

your split("")is null ,you should write split(" ") (double quote with a space)

Answer (score 0):

Rather than using split, I'd think using the string itself will be better.
Try this.

```
Scanner test = new Scanner(System.in);
String[] temp = null;
String line = null;
ArrayList<Integer> artemp = new ArrayList<>();

while(test.hasNext()) {
    line = test.next();
    for(int i = 0; i < line.length; i++)
        artemp.add(Integer.parseInt(""+line.charAt(i));
    for(int i : artemp) System.out.println(i);
}
```