# Getting a NumberFormatException: For input string: "", while parsing inputs into an array

Tags: java, parsing, numberformatexception

```
boolean cloud = false;
//max size of array is 100
int actualLength = 0;
int [] arrayOfInputs = new int[100];
while (!cloud)
{       
    BufferedReader BR = new BufferedReader (new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    //getting the input in string version
    String line = BR.readLine();
    String [ ] splittingThem = line.trim().split(" ");
    actualLength = splittingThem.length;
    //assigning values of array to input
    for (int i = 0; i < actualLength; i++)
    {
        arrayOfInputs[i] = Integer.parseInt(splittingThem[i]);
        if (arrayOfInputs[i]==0)
        {
            cloud = true;
        }
    }

}
//making a new array based off the size of the inputs only
int [] actualArrayOfInputs = new int[actualLength];
for (int i = 0; i < actualLength; i++)
{
        actualArrayOfInputs[i] = arrayOfInputs[i];
}
```

Okay, so my code works fine if I type in "1 2 3 4" but if I copy and paste an input like:

```
33

-55

-44

12312

2778

-3

-2

53211

-1

44

0
```

then I get:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: 
For input string: "" at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65).
```

I don't understand why it's accepting inputs when i'm typing them in but not when i'm trying to paste them in.

I looked up this question on Google and it came up with this solution: [NumberFormatException: For input string: "" while parsing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18952433/numberformatexception-for-input-string-while-parsing), but my code doesn't have that error so I don't know what it is.

Answer (score 0):

You are reading empty lines with this:

```
 String line = BR.readLine();
 String [ ] splittingThem = line.trim().split(" ");
```

The problem does not seem to be on your code, but on your input.
Another point is that you are reading from System.in, if you accidentally press an extra enter, the exception will be thrown.

See what is happening:

1. if the line is ""
2. then the line.trim().split(" ") will still have one element.
   splittingThem.length => 1
3. that will get you into the loop and parse ""-> exception!

Comment: Is there any way for me to work around the input though? This is for a school assignment so I have to get my program to work under the bounds of that input. The potentially"good news" is that for some reason, the exception stopped getting thrown but now all that's being stored into the array (when I copy and paste the vertical input) is a 0.

Comment: That is because, in java, when you create a new array all int values are 0. As you are not modifying the array,arrayOfInputs, it will remain with 0s.

Comment: To get around the input with empty lines, you can try to skip some lines - the even ones, for instance. Or you can verify the length of the line,the string itself, you read, or compare with a known invalid form...now its is logic..

Comment: if(line.isEmpty()){continue;} might help

Comment: Also, please note that the logic is a bit fuzzy here. The array is declared outside the loop, and you always start writing on the array at the position 0. (this might be correct, I dont know what you trying to accomplish). but if you are always starting from zero, for each line you read, witch just contains one number, you will get 99 zeros..